# How to set a column as a string in excel using phpexcel.?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, phpexcel

I need to fetch and store the transaction ID that happens for a transaction. When I click on export to excel, the transaction ID is stored as: **2.02011E+34** . How can I store the complete number in the excel?

I have declared it as:

`$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('AA1', 'Payment Order ID');`

The insertion of entry is done as:

`$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('AA' . (string)($n), $payment_order_id);`

The above line of code is used & $n is set to 2 for the start.

Comment: Add quote char as the first char of the value - in such case Excel treates the value as string strictly and does not use auto-formatting to numeric or date format.

Comment: use as `$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('AA' . $n , $payment_order_id,PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, It's NOT working.

Comment: @Akina, could you please give an example of it?

Comment: @SamarthM add `->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('0')` and try

Comment: *give an example of it* Something like `$this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('AA' . (string)($n), "'".$payment_order_id);` (I do not use PHP)

Comment: Thank you @Akina...
```` $this->excel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueExplicit('AA' . (string)$n, '|' . $payment_order_id . '|'); ````
This code worked....